# R - data.table behavior inconsistent when using quote and eval

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with columns `y` and `x` and I would like to assign the fitted values to one column in the data.table. So I tried the following:

```
q <- quote(predict(lm(y ~ x)))
dt[, predict(lm(y ~ x))]   # works
dt[, eval(q)]              # also works and gives the same result as the line above
dt[, fitted := predict(lm(y ~ x))]  # correctly creates a column with fitted values
dt[, fitted := eval(q)]             # breaks
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

It seems like the behavior regarding `quote` and `eval` is inconsistent depending on whether a new column is created or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: summary: update to the latest version or use `eval(q, .SD)`

Comment: `q <- quote(predict(lm(y ~ x, data=dt)))` would also work, but I have no idea if that would result in additional copies.